# Text moves to bottom when font is changed

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm stuck with a strange problem - inner text of button moves to bottom when I'm trying to change its font (in my case font is Gabriola). Here's my code and screenshots:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/guess_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/main_background" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/top_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/top_bottom_text_shape"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/open_battles"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/back_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/top_text"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/top_text"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/top_text"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back_button_selector"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/back"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="back"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:text="@string/back"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- Other views -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Normal view (default font)]

[image: Font is set to Gabriola]

No other changes are made - I only set text font. Any suggestions?

Comment: check your font file. May be it is made in this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the **FONT** Size of the `Button`

I believe that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that problem was in my font. As it can be seen at the screenshots, Gabriola sized 28sp looks like default android font sized ~20sp, that's why text appears to move down when centred vertically. Finally, I decided to choose another font, and everything works perfect.